# Firebase not getting updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which updates a notes object in the Firebase Realtime Database on certain conditions.

This is the common code called when I need to update any note

```
public final class FirebaseUtils{
public static void updateNote(Context context, Note currentNote) {
        Timber.i("Update note called with note %s", currentNote.toString());
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            return;
        }
        HashMap<String, Object> noteMap = currentNote.getNoteMap();
        String noteId = currentNote.getId();
        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Timber.i("Id is %s", noteId);

        mDatabase.getReference(AppConstants.REFERENCE_USERS)
                .child(userId)
                .child(AppConstants.USER_NOTES)
                .child(noteId)
                .setValue(noteMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Timber.i("Note updated successfully");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Edited note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Timber.e("Error updating note %s", task.getException().getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error editing note", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Cases when note is updated

- **OnBackPressed in a specific activity**

The onBackPressed callback is overriden and the note is updated there.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        String title = titleNotesAdd.getText().toString().trim();
        String content = edtContent.toHtml().trim();
        currentNote.setTitle(title);
        currentNote.setContent(content);

        if (CURRENT_ACTION.equals(AppConstants.ACTION_ADD_NEW_NOTE)) {
            currentNote.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            FirebaseUtils.addNoteToUser(this, currentNote.getNoteMap());
        } else if (CURRENT_ACTION.equals(AppConstants.ACTION_EDIT_NOTE)) {
            FirebaseUtils.updateNote(this, currentNote);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

- **It is updated from a function on click of a bottom sheet item**

  ```
      public void setRemainder(){
      currentNote.setRemainderSet(true);
      currentNote.setRemainderTime(remainder.getTimeInMillis());

      Utils.scheduleAlarm(this, currentNote);

      FirebaseUtils.updateNote(this, currentNote);
      }
  ```

When the back button is pressed, the note is getting updated fine in the Firebase Real-time Database. But when the setRemainder method is called, the note is not being updated in the database.

Why is this happening? Did I miss something?

Comment: did you make sure that ``FirebaseUtils.updateNote`` is getting called?

Comment: It is getting called on back press. It is not getting called at the setRemainder function. That is the problem. The code isn't commented out.  But its not getting called. Idk how thats possible

Comment: Could you show the code where ``setRemainder()`` is being used?

Comment: It is being used in a call back function from a time picker widget. Everything executes except the call to update the note.